# Is there a way to remove the 8.3 filename limitation on the SD.h library?

Tags: library, sd-card, sd.h

I need to be able to create text files on my SD card that are with names longer than 8 characters (which is what the SD.h currently limits me to). A choice would be to move to the SDFat library but before considering that option, is there a way to just remove the limit on the SD.h (because my code already implements the good-old SD.h)? What would be the best way to go about this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 8.3 "limit" is not a "limit" that can be removed. It is how FAT filesystems work.  Longer filenames are a "fudge" extension overlaid on top of that fileststem structure. To be able to use them you would need to implement that extension.

Simpler to switch to a more modern implementation.  FatFS is your friend:

- LFN support, including UTF
- Faster device access
- More efficient
- Can handle more devices than just SD cards
- Can handle multiple devices at once

There is an implementation [here](https://github.com/gallegojm/Arduino-FatFs) though I don't know how good it is (I use it on chipKIT where it is bundled by default).

If you can't get FatFs then basically *anything* is better than the SD library to be brutally honest.

Comment: What about the SDFat library? Is it better than the FatFS? My aim is to not take too much flash memory.

Comment: I haven't used it. But as I mention - anything is better than SD.h. If you have it / can get it easily, then use it.